# How to ORDER mysql rows by multiple columns?

Tags: mysql

such as "order by col_location", if location is the same, then "order by col_time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can string columns in an ORDER BY, separated by commas.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM something
ORDER BY col_location, col_time DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said,listing the different columns in order of priority. You can also go one step further and build logic into your `ORDER BY` so that it becomes conditional e.g.

```
order by case when col_location = col_something_else then 
   col_location 
else 
   col_time 
end
```